# control not positioning right

Tags: wpf, xaml

I wantto postion control like this pic
[image]

I need Next and previous buttons to be as `pic 1`, but i get the following, and not able to solve this.
[image]

Please guide, XAML code:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="4">
        <Grid x:Name="GridNavigation">
            <Button x:Name="Gridprevbutton" Content="Previous" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,0,0,0"></Button>
            <Button x:Name="Gridnextbutton" Content="Next" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="231 , 0, 0, 0"></Button>
            <Button x:Name="Gridendexambuton" Content="End Exam" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,5,0"></Button>
        </Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5,10,0" TextDecorations="Underline">Contact Support</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

**(Edit)** I end up doing this following @davisoa advise. and got it working.

Code behind

```
private void SetNavigation()
{
    var img = Common.AddImageToContainer("images/lowerleftblock.png", GridNavigation, Common.ToDictionaryTLST("top", "left", "none"));
        img.Margin = new Thickness(0,16,0,0);
        Panel.SetZIndex(img, -1);       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your image a top margin to bring it down by however much is needed.
E.g.

```
<Image x:Name="Lowerleftblock" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,20,0,0"></Image>
```

Comment: +1 thanks, following ur's & @davisoa i got it working

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the `Grid` you are not showing above (the first `StackPanel` is in `Grid.Row="4"`) is limiting the height of your Next and Previous buttons.

This example XAML shows the Question block lower than the buttons.

- Changed `Image` to a `StackPanel` with a `Label`, since I don't have your image
- Changed `VerticalAlignment` to `Bottom`, to ensure it floats on the bottom of the `Grid`
- Gave the `Grid` a fixed `Height` to ensure the vertical layout is correct.  You probably don't want to do this

---

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="4">
    <Grid x:Name="GridNavigation" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="75">
        <StackPanel x:Name="Lowerleftblock" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="Green">
          <Label>Question: 1 of 27</Label>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="Gridprevbutton" Content="Previous" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,0,0,0"></Button>
        <Button x:Name="Gridnextbutton" Content="Next" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="231 , 0, 0, 0"></Button>
        <Button x:Name="Gridendexambuton" Content="End Exam" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,5,0"></Button>
    </Grid>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5,10,0" TextDecorations="Underline">Contact Support</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: i did as you describes, but now the buttons are far from Lowerleftblock

Comment: The button's location are completely dependent on their margin - change the margin, or you could change the `Grid` to a `StackPanel` with `Orientation="Horizontal"` and remote the button's `Margin`

Comment: I forgot I gave the `Grid` a fixed height - you don't want that, and would cause what you see in your new image (lots of vertical space between the image and buttons)